# how to get repeatable graphviz layout?

Tags: awk, sed, sh, graphviz, macports

I'm developing a script that can highlight dependencies between packages installed by the MacPorts package manager under OS X.  The script takes an optional argument to highlight a package and all the things that depend upon it in the graph.   When I change the package specified, the whole layout of the graph changes.  What I want to do is use dot to highlight different packages so I can flip back and forth between the two graphs and show the two different dependencies and changes from before/after package installs to illustrate how the package tree changes to others.

What do I need to specify during the auto-construction of the .gv file to make sure that the locations don't change when I specify another highlighted package?

Code is on GitHub:

https://github.com/esba1ley/MacPortsVizTools

An example of this is invoking the script to highlight depndencies on jpeg and tiff are in the "examples" directory in the repo.  Compare the two PDFs in there to see how the structure changes between the two invocations in the shell script for the example.

Comment: The last I knew, `graphviz` alone could not do this. In theory, you would need *both* graphs as input, so that you could identify the nodes that are common to both graphs, and which nodes are unique to one graph. Given that information, you would then need to generate the two layouts in tandem, so that you can place the common nodes in a common, fixed location that won't interfere with the placement of unique nodes in either graph. It's quite a hairy optimization problem.

Comment: Make each package a layer in a multi-layer graph.  (see the documentation for the layer attribute and https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)  Note that postscript (and maybe pdf) are the only output formats that are useful.